# Actors: handle request timeout

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-http

I'm using Scala AKKA HTTP and AKKA Actors to implement a RESTful service.

I'm facing an issue due a request timeout, waiting for a response of an Actor. I'm aware that actors should always send a message/response to the sender().

A synchronous POST request is waiting for the response, until reaching the default request timeout period  (According to [Timeouts](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/timeouts.html#server-timeouts), the default request timeout is 20seconds).

**A response is returned to the client, but Actor continues its execution**. After 60 seconds (the timeout value that i have defined), an AskTimeOutException is returned. But actor execution continues executing the request after that (correct me if i'm wrong).

How to handle this situation ?
There is any way to stop/restart the actor when request timeout is returned ? Or should i protect my code to prevent any blocking situation ?

**MyActor.scala**

```scala
object MyActor
{
  def props(): Props = Props(classOf[MyActor])
  
  def propsWithSmallestMailboxPool(nrOfInstances: Int = 3): Props =
    props().withRouter(SmallestMailboxPool(nrOfInstances = nrOfInstances))

  sealed abstract trait Request
  final case class AddEntity(entity: Entity) extends Request

  sealed abstract trait Response
  final case class EntityCreated(entity: Entity) extends Response
}

class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive = {  
    case request: Request => 
       request match {
         case AddEntity(entity) =>
           sender() ! addEntity(entity)
    }
   }
}
```

**Route.scala**

```scala
  implicit def exceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler = routesExceptionHandler

  lazy val myActor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(MyActor.propsWithSmallestMailboxPool())

  val entityRoute: Route = {
    path("entity") {
      post {
        operationName("addEntity") {
          entity(as[Entity]) { entity => 
             onSuccess(myActor ? MyActor.AddEntity(entity)) {
              case r: MyActor.EntityCreated => 
                 complete(StatusCodes.Created)
              case Failure(ex) =>
                 complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)  
          }
         }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to cancel the `addEntity` execution in `MyActor` if it doesn't finish on time? Is that your ask?

Comment: @Yik San Chan, yep that's right.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to cancel the execution? Because the `addEntity` operation in the actor is blocking?

Comment: Client when invoking POST request receives a response with the request timeout (my default exception handler ensures that), but it is a bit strange that Actor continues the execution and eventually succeeds (inserts the entity at database).


Client will retry the operation but it fails because it already exists.

To be fair, `addEntity` blocks because it invokes Avro SchemaRegistry REST API and it blocks waiting for a response. Maybe the whole solution for my problem is to return an error if Schema Registry is unavailable; or using cache mechanisms (to cache schemas)

Comment: First of all, an HTTP call doesn't have to be blocking: simply use a Future API to invoke the SchemaRegistry REST API? Second, maybe always check if the entity has already existed in DB before inserting?

Comment: Ok. Right now, i'm changing my external calls to async methods and using CircuitBreaker pattern to wrap those calls to enforce call timeout and fail-fast.